# ASP.Net make it work with a different format of jsonstring

Tags: vb.net, json

I have created this vb.net file and it is working when i send a string like this:

```
?data={"id":"12345","timestamp":"2012-03-03 12:00:00","latitude":"23.41223","longitude"="54.12345"}
```

but i also want it to work with a format like this:

```
?id=12345&timestamp=2012-03-03 12:00:00&latitude=23.41223&longitude=54.12345
```

How do i make this work in my vb.net file

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load    
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString("data")) Then
            Dim data As String = Request.QueryString("data")

            Dim myObj As New MyObject
            Dim properties() As PropertyInfo = myObj.GetType().GetProperties()
            Dim values() As String = Server.UrlDecode(data).Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "").Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "").Replace(""":""", """=""").Split(New Char() {","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            For Each value As String In values
                Dim keyValue() As String = value.Split(New Char() {"="}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                For Each prop As PropertyInfo In properties
                    If prop.Name.ToLower = keyValue(0).ToLower.Replace("""", "") Then
                        prop.SetValue(myObj, keyValue(1).Replace("""", ""), Nothing)
                    End If
                Next
            Next


        lblText1.Text = String.Format("ID: {0}", myObj.ID)
        lblText2.Text = String.Format("Longitude: {0}", myObj.Longitude)
        lblText3.Text = String.Format("Latitude: {0}", myObj.Latitude)
        lblText4.Text = String.Format("Timestamp: {0}", myObj.Timestamp)



    Cmd.Parameters.Clear()      
    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", myObj.ID)
    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Longitude", myObj.Longitude)
    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Latitude", myObj.Latitude)
    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Timestamp", myObj.Timestamp)

    Con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=servert\sql;Initial Catalog=table;Integrated Security=True"
        Cmd.Connection = Con
        Con.Open()
    Cmd.CommandText = "IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Locatie WHERE id = @ID) " & Environment.NewLine & _
                  "  BEGIN UPDATE Locatie SET Longitude = @Longitude, Latitude = @Latitude, Timestamp = @Timestamp WHERE id=@ID END " & Environment.NewLine & _
                  "ELSE " & Environment.NewLine & _
                  "   BEGIN INSERT INTO Locatie VALUES (@ID, @Longitude, @Latitude, @Timestamp) END "


     Reader = Cmd.ExecuteReader

        Reader.Close()
       Con.Close()
       Con.Dispose()



        End If

    End Sub

    Public Class MyObject
        Private _ID As String
        Private _Longitude As String
        Private _Latitude As String
        Private _Timestamp As String


        Public Property ID As String
            Get
                Return _ID
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                _ID = value
            End Set
        End Property


        Public Property Longitude As String
            Get
                Return _Longitude
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                _Longitude = value
            End Set
        End Property


        Public Property Latitude As String
            Get
                Return _Latitude
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                _Latitude = value
            End Set
        End Property


        Public Property Timestamp As String
            Get
                Return _Timestamp
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                _Timestamp = value
            End Set
        End Property


    End Class





</script>
```

Where probably the key must be around here, so that there is also a second option where the second string is split set the values as id, longitude, latitude and timestamp:

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load   
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString("data")) Then
            Dim data As String = Request.QueryString("data")

            Dim myObj As New MyObject
            Dim properties() As PropertyInfo = myObj.GetType().GetProperties()
            Dim values() As String = Server.UrlDecode(data).Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "").Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "").Replace(""":""", """=""").Split(New Char() {","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            For Each value As String In values
                Dim keyValue() As String = value.Split(New Char() {"="}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                For Each prop As PropertyInfo In properties
                    If prop.Name.ToLower = keyValue(0).ToLower.Replace("""", "") Then
                        prop.SetValue(myObj, keyValue(1).Replace("""", ""), Nothing)
                    End If
                Next
            Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a check on the query string. If the string starts with data, then allocate values to the variables using the first method, else allocate values to variables by getting the value of the query string.

Example:

```
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString("data")) Then
    'Use reflection logic
Else
    MyObj.Longitude = Request.QueryString("longitude")
End If
```

**Edit**

Example of the implementation within the provided Page_Load subroutine.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load 
    Dim myObj As New MyObject

    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString("data")) Then
        Dim data As String = Request.QueryString("data")

        Dim properties() As PropertyInfo = myObj.GetType().GetProperties()
        Dim values() As String = Server.UrlDecode(data).Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "").Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "").Replace(""":""", """=""").Split(New Char() {","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        For Each value As String In values
            Dim keyValue() As String = value.Split(New Char() {"="}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            For Each prop As PropertyInfo In properties
                If prop.Name.ToLower = keyValue(0).ToLower.Replace("""", "") Then
                    prop.SetValue(myObj, keyValue(1).Replace("""", ""), Nothing)
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Else
        If Not (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString("id")) Then
            myObj.ID = Request.QueryString("id")
        Else
            myObj.ID = "Not set"
        End If

        If Not (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString("longitude")) Then
            myObj.Longitude = Request.QueryString("longitude")
        Else
            myObj.Longitude = "Not set"
        End If

        If Not (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString("latitude")) Then
            myObj.Latitude = Request.QueryString("latitude")
        Else
            myObj.Latitude = "Not set"
        End If

        If Not (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString("timestamp")) Then
            myObj.Timestamp = Request.QueryString("timestamp")
        Else
            myObj.Timestamp = "Not set"
        End If  
    End If

    lblText1.Text = String.Format("ID: {0}", myObj.ID)
    lblText2.Text = String.Format("Longitude: {0}", myObj.Longitude)
    lblText3.Text = String.Format("Latitude: {0}", myObj.Latitude)
    lblText4.Text = String.Format("Timestamp: {0}", myObj.Timestamp)

    'Rest of sub here
End Sub
```

Comment: I get no errors, but i am not getting anything back. How can i return this so i can see what the values are?

Comment: Is it maybe because the function of setting the MyObj is in the If it contains data...?

Comment: Yes you need to move that out and rearrage your code accordingly. I have edited my code to give you an idea of the implementation. I hope it helps!

Comment: Okay, well i have a little problem. The code with ?id=12345&timestamp=2012-03-03 12:00:00&latitude=23.41223&longitude=54.12345
 is working, the only thing is that the first string isnt working anymore

Comment: Isnt it because after If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString("data")) Then it also fires the else function because of the Next Next in it?

Comment: No that won't be the case because the next next is two for loops within the first if. The query string is case sensitive so if "data" does not appear in the querystring as a key, it will run the else. You could "watch" your QueryString based on the ID you are using and debug the Page_Load to isolate the problem. Also make sure that the copy of the code is correct and that you didn't accidently move a piece of code.